# Пул коннектов к базе и сервлет

Tags: java, servlet, mysql

Есть простой сервлет, выполняет post/get-запросы по нажатию на разные кнопки на JSP-страничке. Эти кнопки вызывают методы, которые взаимодействуют с базой данных (типа добавить/считать какие-то значения по ключам). В классе, где представлена реализация этих методов создается пул коннектов к базе (c3p0 DataSource).

Но при запуске севрлета и попытке просто считать значения ругается на этот самый пул коннектов. Т.е. пишет какие-то эксепшены типа - не могу создать пул коннектов и все в таком роде. Тоже самое ругается на логирование...

Нужно ли этот пул коннектов и логирование как-то указывать в web.xml? Есть ли какие-нибудь примеры, как это правильно делать для подобных проектов?

Comment: обычно такими ресурсами как конекшны к субд управляет контейнер, поэтому ресурс этот настраивается в самом аппликейшн сервере. если же вы создаете соединение к субд сами в коде значит вы это делаете не совсем так как надо (т.е или добавить пул соединений или если это поддерживает сам драйвер указать количество конекшнов в пуле). к сожалению примеры конфигурации субд для апликейшн сервера показать не получится т.к. настройка будет отличатся для разных серверов

Comment: @jmu обычно такими ресурсами управляет та часть системы, которая удобна для конкретного разработчика. Не стоит морочить голову настройкой ресурсов в контейнере. Тем более, что сделать это из кода - не проблема.

Comment: @drcosmo "какие-то эксепшны" - это разговор не по существу. Код и стектрейс в студию, а то гадание на кофейной гуще выходит.